# docker login self hosted registry = x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: ssl, docker

I am new to docker and trying to setup my registry for docker swarm.

I have three debian installations interacting with each other:

- registry
- website
- database

Trying to setup my database separate from my website and my registry separate too.

My `registry machine` also hosts a website let say `vmreg.com` managed by `letsencrypt` ssl certificates. I use this certificate to sign both my website and registry.

`docker run -d --restart=always --name registry -v` $(pwd)`/etc/letsencrypt/live/vmreg.com:/etc/letsencrypt/live/vmreg.com -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/letsencrypt/live/vmreg.com/domain.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/etc/letsencrypt/live/vmreg.com/domain.key -p 5000:5000 registry:2`

On my database machine I can login just fine:
`echo "password" | docker login -u username --password-stdin  vmreg.com:5000`

but on my `website machine` I get `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` when I try to login

Only difference is that my `website machine` also has its own `letsencrypt` domain setup. I don't understand why I get this error. Is it a possible conflict ?

Solutions I found online all talk about copying certificates but 1) I have not copied any cert on my `database machine` and 2) I don't understand why I would need to copy certificates from the registry server to a client; that makes no sense to me because what happens when I renew my certs